# Tag Helpers disabled in VS 2015

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, tag-helpers

I am having trouble getting Tag Helpers enabled in my project.

Here is a summary of the project setup:

- VS 2015 RC Community Edition.
- Project.json reference: `Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc": "6.0.0-beta4`
- _GlobalImport.chtml has `@addTagHelper"*,Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.TagHelpers"`

No build errors or warnings.

Must missing something, but I don't know what.

**UPDATE:**

Seems I am part of the way there. I added `@addTagHelper "*, Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.TagHelpers"` to the `_ViewStart.chtml.` Razor is now processing things like `<a asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Summary" title="Manage">TEST</a>` as a link with a proper href attribute. However intellisense on not working.

Comment: See Authoring   taghelpers http://bit.ly/1Mqd0th

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) In your `project.json` `dependencies`, make sure you have these 3:

```
"Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc": "1.0.1",
"Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers": "1.0.1",
"Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Tools": {
  "version": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
  "type": "build"
},
```

2) In your `project.json` `tools`, make sure you have:

```
"Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Tools": "1.0.0-preview2-final"
```

3) In Your `Views\_ViewImports.cshtml`, make sure you have:

```
@addTagHelper *, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers
```

Then `rebuild` the project and you should be good to go. (If not try restarting VS.)

Comment: I setting this response as an answer since it's reflects how I am setting up my projects currently. But the truth is I have not experienced this issue in some time.

Answer (score 3):

After much back and forth I got the intellisense working.

As mentioned in the question update, I needed to add `@addTagHelper "Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.TagHelpers"`

Finally, I looked at the NuGet page for tag helpers. I noticed some listed dependencies were not in my project. I added those, restarted VS, and got some intellisense.

Comment: How about steps for this last comment.

Comment: @Sam, The question may be moot at this point. When I asked, I was using 1.0.0-beta5. I have not experienced this issue with the very latest ASP.Net and VS 2015 versions.

Comment: Adding @addTagHelper "Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.TagHelpers" to _ViewImports.cshtml is what got it working for me.
Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Try to add dependency `"Microsoft.AspNet.Tooling.Razor": "1.0.0-beta5"` to your project.json.

That fixed a similar issue for me.

Comment: That and a restart of VS. Rebuilding alone isn't enough.

Comment: The restart did it.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I needed to deactivate the IntelliSense of ReSharper (9.2) which overrides the TagHelpers.

See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40630217/909980