# How can I get Intellisense for the tag helpers in VS 2015 MVC Core project?

Tags: razor, asp.net-core, tag-helpers

In my Razor Views I can get intelligence for my model in most places like HTML Helpers but just not inside tag helpers.

I tried everything at these two links:
1) [MVC 6 Tag Helpers Intellisense?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34098543/mvc-6-tag-helpers-intellisense)
2) [Tag Helpers disabled in VS 2015](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30965430/tag-helpers-disabled-in-vs-2015/40147096#40147096)

And it doesn't help.

I am following the Microsoft tutorial at:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/first-mvc-app/adding-model
and they clearly show intellisense for a tag helper in the screen shot at the bottom.
Has anyone run into this and found the magic bullet here?

---

Intellisense for taghelpers seems to be working now.
Not sure if this is from the steps above and if they worked.
Will keep updated as I try in other projects and other development computers.

Comment: Did you tried restarting VS2015?

Comment: Yes, restarted it.